# Convert char var to integer for use in join

Tags: sql, postgresql, crystal-reports

I am trying to get a report to run through crystal using our postgres databse.

My SQL looks like

```
SELECT 
    slcnote.note_date, 
    slcnote.account, 
    customer.name, 
    slcnote.reference,
    slcnote.operator,
    salesman.name,  
    slcnote.system_date,
    slcnote.note_type, 
    slcnote.note_note,
                CAST(salesman.code as integer)
FROM   
   slcnote
    Left JOIN customer ON slcnote.account=customer.account
    left JOIN salesman ON slcnote.operator=salesman.code
 ORDER BY "slcnote"."note_date"
```

However it does not seem to be converting the salesman code to an integer. I am encountering the following error message in Crystal Reports:

```
--------------------------- Crystal Reports --------------------------- 
Failed to retrieve data from the database. 
Details: 42883:
ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = character varying; 
Error while executing the query 
[Database Vendor Code: 7 ] 
--------------------------- OK ---------------------------
```

Thanks for help

Chris

Comment: Does salesman.code contains non numeric characters?

Comment: What `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Ah sorry yes, mean the Join not where.. no it only has integer chracters

Comment: If you're doing a join on mis-matched types you'll need to cast or convert them, but keep in mind this usually leads to abysmal performance. Try and normalize the type across all tables.

Comment: And what do you mean "it does not seem"? What exactly is happening?

Comment: Unfortunatly I cannot change the table itself.  I am converting them in the select using cast.  The error I am receiving is  ---------------------------
Crystal Reports
---------------------------
Failed to retrieve data from the database.
Details: 42883:ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = character varying;
Error while executing the query [Database Vendor Code: 7 ]
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

Comment: why not to use `to_number` function e.g. `slcnote.operator=TO_NUMBER(salesman.code)`

Comment: TO_Number doesnt work error message is ....function to_number(character varying) does not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you cast `salesman.code` to an integer in the `SELECT` clause, but not in the `ON` clause. Therefore, the query is trying to join tables by comparing an `integer` to a `VARCHAR`, which generates the error message.

To solve your immediate problem, you need to perform the cast in your `ON` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM slcnote
    LEFT JOIN salesman ON CAST(salesman.code AS INT) = slcnote."operator"
```

As noted in comments, however, performance of this query will be abysmal. If you can't change the table, are you able to create a materialized view that performs the cast? This might help. You should also see if the individual who *is* able to change the table will do so, citing these performance issues.